# Sonoma update results in disk bloat

Tags: spotlight, sonoma

After updating to 14.1.1, something creates 35 GB files in HD/Users/username/Library/Application Support/FileProvider/number/wharf/wharf/propagate. I have turned off OneDrive, Dropbox, and Google Drive by disallowing background access. But something running continues to make a new file every five minutes until the drive is full. Calls to Apple didn't ID the problem which they believe is 3rd party application produced as it is in my User directory. I think it may have some relationship to spotlight, as invoking a spotlight reindex by dragging the HD into spotlight Privacy and out (per Apple) did eliminate the files - which have an 8-digit numeric name. I dropped my whole drive into Spotlight privacy, hoping to fix it, but the files (all about the same 35 GB size) reappear.

Comment: The link above to the "question already exists" is dead.